# Linux system call: getaddrinfo return -2

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm using the system call getaddrinfo and it return -2. I try to know what is this error and get that ths is "name or service not known".
the name - it is my host name and I'm sure it is known. but the service is a number that is changed from run to run. how can I know that I am bringing the correct parameter?

my code:

```
int GetSockPeerIPs(int sock, AddressList &addresses, int &error,
                  int family, bool zeroport)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
    socklen_t salen = sizeof(ss);
    struct sockaddr *sa;
    struct addrinfo hints, *paddr, *paddrp;

    sa = (struct sockaddr *)&ss;

    if (getpeername(sock, sa, &salen) != 0) {
        error = errno;
        return -1;
    }

    char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST];
    char pbuf[NI_MAXSERV];
    if (0 != (error = getnameinfo(sa, salen,
                      hbuf, sizeof(hbuf),
                      pbuf, sizeof(pbuf),
                      0))) {
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    if (ATNetworkTool::AF_XINETX == family) {
        hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    } else {
        hints.ai_family = family;
    }
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    if (0 != (error = getaddrinfo(hbuf, pbuf, &hints, &paddrp))) {
        return -1;
    }
    addresses.clear();
    for (paddr = paddrp; paddr; paddr = paddr->ai_next) {
        if (ATNetworkTool::AF_XINETX == family) {
            if (!ATAddress::saIsInet(paddr->ai_addr)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (zeroport) {
            addresses.insert(ATAddress(paddr->ai_addr, 0));
        } else {
            addresses.insert(paddr->ai_addr);
        }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(paddrp);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks!
gln

Comment: Note, if getaddrinfo() and friends fail, you can call [gai_strerror()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gai_strerror.html) on the return code to get a textual error message. e.g. `printf("getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));` in your case

Comment: FTR, getaddrinfo is not going to be a system call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error code.  Have you thought about finding out what it means?  On this occasion I have done it for you.  But here's what I did so you can look it up for yourself next time.

Looking at the man page for [getaddrinfo()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) I found it can return a number of error codes e.g. EAI_AGAIN.  The numeric values will be defined in a header file somewhere, so I did

```
cd /usr/include
find . -name "*.h" -exec grep -l EAI_AGAIN {} \;
```

This identified netdb.h.  So I opened that in vi and this is what it said:

```
# define EAI_BADFLAGS     -1    /* Invalid value for `ai_flags' field.  */
# define EAI_NONAME       -2    /* NAME or SERVICE is unknown.  */
# define EAI_AGAIN        -3    /* Temporary failure in name resolution.  */
# define EAI_FAIL         -4    /* Non-recoverable failure in name res.  */
# define EAI_FAMILY       -6    /* `ai_family' not supported.  */
# define EAI_SOCKTYPE     -7    /* `ai_socktype' not supported.  */
# define EAI_SERVICE      -8    /* SERVICE not supported for `ai_socktype'.  */
# define EAI_MEMORY       -10   /* Memory allocation failure.  */
# define EAI_SYSTEM       -11   /* System error returned in `errno'.  */
# define EAI_OVERFLOW     -12   /* Argument buffer overflow.  */
```

So basically, the name or service that you are passing in is unknown to getaddrinfo.  I'd check to see whether the first two parameters are reasonable, if I were you.

Comment: FYI `grep -r --include=\*.h EAI_AGAIN /usr/include` would be much more efficient than using `find` to spawn `grep`, since it only spawns a single `grep` process instead of one process for each header file.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Correct, but who cares as long as it gets the job done?

Comment: Have you ever had to grep a source tree with tens of thousands of files?  A single grep instance runs in a couple of seconds.  Forking a new process for each file takes significantly longer, on the order of minutes or more.

Comment: @Adam:  yes.  On no machine I have worked on since the mid 1980's has grep taken "a couple of seconds" on a file the size of a typical C header.  Also, back then, the `-r` flag and `--include` flag didn't exist.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with your approach for this problem -- for a file tree the size of `/usr/include`, it won't make much of a difference -- but for larger problems, it will make a difference.  You probably didn't have code bases with tens of thousands of files in them in the mid-80's.  And sure, if you're using an antiquated grep that doesn't have `-r` or `--include`, then go ahead and use `find`, but most greps these days have those flags.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo` is picky about the format of the data, in parsing config files make sure you have no extra spaces normally trailing spaces in the host name parameter or you will get this error, in this instance the error is correct, just not very informative.